# Execute dynamic SQL within context of BigQuery SELECT

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I have a pretty special use case - which may seem crazy - but I think it's a reasonable extreme edge case, and I think the answer is "it's just not possible in any way" but I'm asking all the same in case someone has an idea.

We have a huge amount of KPIs. I want to define them in a central dbt seed (relatively static table). Schema would be something like:

- some
- join
- keys
- kpi_name (e.g. `"actions"`)
- kpi_sql_expr (e.g. `` IF(`action_type` = "foo", `action_count`, 0) ``)

I then want to join this from my BigQuery table (dbt model) based on the join keys and execute the kpi_sql_expr and store the value in a column called kpi_name (well, i'd probably store the information in a single JSON column called kpi because there could be more than 1 kpi_name for the row in question - but that's a specialisation of this use case and not core to the question). This would allow me to maintain the logic in one place and then use a generic pattern in the large number of models where I need to do this sort of thing without having to hand-curate KPIs in many, many places.

The problem I am running into as I've thought about how to solve this (and I've considered some ghastly implementations using all manner of sql/javascript UDFs) is that fundamentally, I can't run a procedural statement (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) in a SELECT context, no matter how I try to hack it. Jinja also can't help me because this sql_expr is row-level.

The ONLY way I can conceive of this being possible is to use dbt `post-hook` to call a BigQuery stored procedure where I could do something ghastly like a DML update that populates this column (presumably added as NULL in my model) based on a combination of procedural stuff and select stuff. Anything like this in a post-hook is a total abuse - but I can't create some new table otherwise it would be missing from dbt's lineage - so I'd have to alter the relation just created by DBT.

Actually, I'm not even sure how I could even achieve this within a stored procedure - I still have the fundamental problem of needing to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE within a SELECT context.

Welcoming any ideas. Please trust that I have a good reason for wanting this - even if the conclusion ends up being "there's no sane way to do this".

Comment: You cannot start an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in a `SELECT`. This would be a security nightmare, because if an admin would query your view, it could run all the code with higher privilege. The only way to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to create your desired SELECT statement. Could your KPI be created by UDFs? An UDF can make use of a select statement to join and window your dataset. However, you need to know the columns before creating the UDF.

Comment: Yea, I know this :). The problem with implementing via UDF is making it generic. I want a generic UDF that can calculate a KPI given some centralised definition. This would be completely trivial within a procedural programming paradigm but very difficult within a SQL context :(. The very thing that varies from 1 KPI calculation to another is the sql expression; the columns referenced, the calculation etc. I don't see a way of making this dynamic without being able to run dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't fully answer my question but I did come up with a workaround and will share for posterity!

Instead of trying to run some per-row dynamic SQL - which is the triad of impossible, a bad idea, and non-performant, I decided that it would be the lesser of two evils to dynamically construct beastly SQL using a jinja macro.

It works like this:

- there is a seed file that maps dbt model names and various criteria to kpi names, expressions, aggregation functions (which wrap the expressions - necessary when this macro is used in an aggregate context - determined by aggregate=true macro parameter)
- a macro is responsible for querying the seed data and producing some brilliantly awful dynamic SQL (snippet posted below)
- to make use of it, my dbt model simply needs to call the macro in its select statement

Macro:

```sql
{% macro add_kpis_column(aggregate=true) -%}

{%- set sql_statement -%}
  WITH `kpi_seed_sql_expression` AS (
    SELECT * EXCEPT(`sql_expression`),
      CONCAT(
        "WHEN ",
        IFNULL(
          NULLIF(
            ARRAY_TO_STRING([
              IF(`APClient` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT("`APClient` = '", `APClient`, "'"), NULL),
              IF(`parent_kpi_type` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT("`parent_kpi_type` = '", `parent_kpi_type`, "'"), NULL),
              IF(`parent_campaign_id` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT("`parent_campaign_id` = ", `parent_campaign_id`), NULL)
            ], " AND "),
            ""
          ),
          "TRUE"
        ),
        " THEN ",
        {{ "CONCAT(`sql_aggregation_function`, '(', `sql_expression`, ')')" if aggregate else "`sql_expression`" }}
      ) AS `sql_expression`
    FROM {{ ref("kpis") }}
    WHERE `table_name` = "{{ this.identifier }}"
  ),

  `kpi_name_sql_expression` AS (
    SELECT
      `kpi_name`,
      CONCAT(
        "CASE ",
        STRING_AGG(`sql_expression`, "\n" ORDER BY `APClient` DESC, `parent_kpi_type` DESC, `parent_campaign_id` DESC),
        " END AS `",
        `kpi_name`,
        "`"
      ) AS `sql_expression`
    FROM `kpi_seed_sql_expression`
    GROUP BY `kpi_name`
  )

  SELECT CONCAT(
    "TO_JSON(STRUCT(",
    STRING_AGG(`sql_expression`, ", "),
    "))"
  ) AS `sql_expression`
  FROM `kpi_name_sql_expression`

{%- endset -%}

{%- if execute %}
    {%- set result = run_query(sql_statement) -%}
{% else %}
    {%- set result = [[]] -%}
{% endif -%}

{{ result[0][0] }} AS `kpis`

{%- endmacro %}
```

Example usage from dbt model:

```
SELECT *, {{ add_kpi_columns(aggregate=false) }}
FROM ...
```

This has effect of adding a single column called kpis, whose value is a JSON that maps kpi names to values.

Thinking about it, this doesn't need to be a JSON, it could be a struct. Anyway, there you have it.